If a sincere muslim commits major shirk/major kufr is he labelled a mushrik/kafir
In footnotes of the translation of book "Bad al amali" it's mentioned that if a believer commits grevious sin he isn't a disbeliever.

We, the Ahl al-Sunnah say
that regardless of the enormity of a person’s sin, he remains a believer; and Allāh may
punish him or forgive him.

Additionally the SINCERE muslims among bani israil who worshipped calf weren't labelled mushrikun in quran.
Another relevant incident from sunni corpus is about a man who asked his sons to burn him and disperse his ashes in the sea so that Allah cannot catch him . Isn't this major kufr to deny the ressurection ability of Allah?
I am not sure the incident of prophet Adam eating from the tree can fit the above category.
Therefore the question are sincere muslims not labelled kaafir/mushrik if they commit major shirk/major kufr.
I am not taking into consideration the concept of Establishment of proof since I am asking this question for sincere muslims only. Sincere muslims promptly accept the mistake once told .

assalam alaikom Sincere Muslims who commit major sins are not automatically considered disbelievers. The major sin might be an act of rebellion or disobedience, but as long as they don't outright deny the fundamental tenets of Islam, they remain Muslim.
Imam al-Nawawi (in Sharh Sahih Muslim) explained that a person who commits major sins (e.g., adultery, alcohol, or even shirk out of ignorance) is not excommunicated from Islam unless they reject Allah's core commands.
Sahih Muslim (Hadith 349) – The Prophet (SAW) said:
"Whoever says 'La ilaha illallah' (there is no god but Allah) and dies upon that, will enter Paradise.
The Qur'an mentions that those who worshipped the golden calf among Bani Israel repented and were forgiven, indicating they were not considered mushrikun forever.
Surah Al-A'raf (7:153):
"But those who committed [the sin] and repented and believed and did righteous work... Indeed, your Lord is thereafter Forgiving and Merciful.
https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/90902/the-children-of-israels-worship-of-the-calf
On the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him), who said that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
A man sinned greatly against himself, and when death came to him he charged his sons, saying: When I have died, burn me, then crush me and scatter [my ashes] into the sea, for, by Allah, if my Lord takes possession of me, He will punish me in a manner in which He has punished no one [else]. So they did that to him. Then He said to the earth: Produce what you have taken-and there he was! And He said to him: What induced you to do what you did? He said: Being afraid of You, O my Lord (or he said: Being frightened of You) and because of that He forgave him. It was related by Muslim (also by al-Bukhari, an-Nasa'i and Ibn Majah)
Reference    : Hadith 32, 40 Hadith Qudsi
.
It is not permissible to declare a servant a non-Muslim due to his sins. A believer with sins that does not repent then his affair is with his Lord; if He wills He can punish him, and if He wills He can forgive him. This belief of |Ahlus Sunnah Wal-Jama. Unlike the belief of the Khawarij and Murjia’. This doctrine  is established in our sharia as it was established with the people of the book before us . The proof is Allah forgave this man who in lived a life of sin
but the sins that can make you a kafir is leaving the prayer but there is debate
Buraydah reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “The covenant between us and them is the prayer, so whoever abandons it has committed unbelief.”
Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2621
Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Tirmidhi
Abdullah ibn Shaqiq reported: The companions of Muhammad, peace and blessings be upon him, did not consider leaving any deed to be unbelief except for the prayer.
Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2622
Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Nawawi
Al-Miswar ibn Makhramah reported: Umar ibn al-Khattab, may Allah be pleased with him, said, “There is no share of Islam for one who abandons the prayer.”
Source: al-Muwaṭṭa’ 117
Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Albani
Repentance (tawbah) is key. If someone commits a major sin but repents sincerely, Allah's mercy is vast, and they can be forgiven.
Surah At-Tawbah (9:104): "And who is it that forgives sins except Allah?"

Ibn qudamah doesn't hold abandoning of prayer out of lazyness as kufr, neither did nasiruddin albani. May Allah bless you for the efffort
